# What is the convergence criteria of a semi-supervised learning algorithm

Tags: machine-learning, semi-supervised-learning, active-learning

I would like to know about when to stop doing semi supervision? for example, I learn a classifier from a small dataset, and then I use it to label a pool of unlabelled dataset. How long should this process be continued?